# Which is the tintColor of UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonItemStyleDone?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I would like to use a UISegmentedControl with two buttons as a replacement for a single 'Done' button. To achieve this, I need to know the tintColor of UIBarButtonItems with UIBarButtonItemStyleDone.

Cheers and thanks in advance

MrMage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Joe Hewitt's Three20 example project TTCatalog, it's `RGBCOLOR(30, 110, 255)`. So that's what I'm gonna use, too.

Update: `RGBCOLOR(60, 136, 230)` is even better.